# uploading csv file on website and get result

Tags: c#, csv

Dear friends 
I have a console application in which i want to first  sign in and then I press button which directs me to  file upload form .In file upload form I want to upload a csv file and then redirect to next form after clicking submit button then i want to get response of that form .
can any one help me to do this from C# console application?
thanks.

Comment: Which specific bit are you stuck with? What have you tried? Also,  what do you mean by "form", "redirect" and "click" in a console application? Do you mean you want to interact with the website from a console? If so you'll need to look at the http more than the ui.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to upload a file on a website from a console application,
then you should have information about FTP credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a real http-transfer you need to create a http request, I looked around a little bit and found this: [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data), seems to be right. I'm doing something similar in python currently.